# Facebook App via Java Applet

Tags: facebook, jakarta-ee, applet

I have a headless Java EE app running on one of my GlassFish servers, and some time ago I wrote up a Swing applet for its front-end. Now I want to make a FB app that uses the same back-end, but I don't want to rewrite the GUI in JS or PHP.

I absolutely **detest** JavaScript. I've been pouring through the FB dev docs and can't seem to find an answer to this question, but:

**Can I just use my applet as the "canvas" for my FB application?** If the canvas simply uses an iframe, and the canvas url points to a servlet that runs my applet, is there any reason why that wouldn't work?

Comment: "Can I just use my applet as the "canvas" for my FB application?" Yes you could embed the Applet and have it display in the iframe. But you should figure out how the Applet is to communicate with the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works. I read a tutorial to get an applet inside a facebook app using an iframe, so that must work. They had to pass the facebook data in the applet init parameters. there might be another way around to get facebook data into an app if you need that